# Rails: thread_mattr_accessor randomly becoming `nil` in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails `5.2.2.4`, I'm getting this inexplicable behavior where a thread_mattr_accessor is becoming `nil` randomly.

Given this module:

```
module Test

  thread_mattr_accessor :max_installments

  self.max_installments = 12

end
```

Out of 6 pager refreshes (using Puma in development), I get a `comparison of Integer with nil failed` when comparing an integer with that variable.

On the Rails red exception page, I can use the bottom controller to confirm it's actually nil!

However, simply refreshing the page some times, I will eventually get a normal page load with that variable being set.

What might be setting that to nil? There's no code at all that sets that variable anywhere else other than the `self.max_installments=` in the class definition above.

Comment: I'd check the implementation of `thread_mattr_accessor`. Could be a bug in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module Test

```rb
module Test
  thread_mattr_accessor :max_installments
  self.max_installments = 12
end
```

Normal use

```rb
puts "max_installments is: #{Test.max_installments.inspect}"
# max_installments is: 12
```

In Thread use

```rb
Thread.new { puts "max_installments in thread is #{Test.max_installments.inspect}" }
# max_installments in thread is nil
```

Set value inside the thread

```rb
Thread.new do
  Test.max_installments = 99
  puts "max_installments in thread now is #{Test.max_installments.inspect}"
end
# max_installments in thread now is 99

Thread.new { puts "max_installments in another thread is #{Test.max_installments.inspect}" }
# max_installments in another thread is nil

puts "max_installments is: #{Test.max_installments}"
# max_installments is: 12
```

ASAP [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors_per_thread.rb#L143) must be released and we can set a default value to use in threads like this

```rb
module Test
  thread_mattr_accessor :max_installments, default: 12
  self.max_installments = 12
end
```

For now, if you go use inside threads, you need set value before to avoid get nil.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that commit that will enable the possibility of setting a `default`. While that doesn't come, how do you deal with Class-level settings that sometimes need to be changed (for instance, during parallel testing) in a thread-safe way? Using a simple class variable or class instance variable is not thread safe, and using thread_mattr_accessor is not pratical as it is because I can't set it's value on the class itself nor in an initializer, because newly spun Threads wont see it's value.

Comment: I am also looking for a slim and smart alternative @sandre89